# REDSHIFT if value in list

Tags: amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I am trying to set some variables on the top of my query via CTEs to make maintenance of a long query more easy to handle.

I have extracted an example of what I am trying to achieve. I am not managing to make 'tags' be perceived as a list rather than a whole string. I have tried split_part but have not managed to get what I require.

```
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT
    'tag1, tag2, tag3' as tags 
)
select 
CASE WHEN 'tag1' in (select tags from tmp) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END matched_tags
```

Basically what I need is to have a string 'tag1' and see if it exists in the list 'tag1','tag2' or 'tag3'. This should give me 1 as there is a match
This is obviously not working because it is taking the 'tag1, tag2, tag3' as one string so there is no match.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The STRPOS() function should do what you want.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STRPOS.html

Something like this:

```
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT
    'tag1, tag2, tag3' as tags 
)
SELECT 
CASE WHEN STRPOS(tags, 'tag1') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as matched_tags 
FROM tmp;
```